# Replacing JS language file loads old values

Tags: javascript

I've implemented a simple localisation switching in my application. I do it by selecting laguage from a combo (or whatever) and then switching a JS language file with another.

```
function setLang(lang) {
    setCookie('vegindex_lang', lang, 365);

    // Find language 'script' element and replace according to lang
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id && elements[i].id == 'lang') {
            var src = 'JavaScript/Localisation/strings_' + lang + '.js';
            document.head.replaceChild(newElement(src), elements[i]);
            loadStrings();
            break;
        }
    }
}

function newElement(src) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = src;
    s.id = 'lang';

    return s;
}

function loadStrings() {
    // Wizard wrapper window
    wizardWrapper.setTitle(wizard_title);

    // Wizard panel
    wizardButtonDisclaimer.setText(wizard_button_disclaimer);
    wizardButtonBack.setText(wizard_button_back);
    wizardButtonNext.setText(wizard_button_next);

    // Reload wizard
    wizardWrapper.doLayout();
}
```

Typical content of language file:

```
var wizard_title = 'This is english';
var wizard_button_disclaimer = 'Disclaimer';
var wizard_button_back = 'Back';
var wizard_button_next = 'Next';
```

It works fine but always loading the previouse language. That meens that:

- first time language switch - nothing happens
- second time language switch - language switched to the one i chose the first time

looks like the newly injected script file isn't available right efter it's beeing added. Anyone has a clue why that happens?

Comment: Do you have multiple script tags? Using IDs here might be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably because you inject the script-tag, and immediately after that call loadStrings(). The languagefile may still be (down)loading though.

This is called a race-condition. This happening depends on the speed of your internet and several other dependencies and you should always try to avoid that.

You can avoid that for examply by using a scriptloader like labJS (http://labjs.com/), RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/), or any other.
This will let you load the script and wait for it, then when it's been succesfully loaded, execute the loadStrings()-method.

Comment: Thanks very much my friend. The fact that the script takes a bit of time to download just haven't crossed my mind. Using RequireJS solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post the corrected setLang function which includes an implementation with RequireJS:

```
function setLang(lang) {
    setCookie('vegindex_lang', lang, 365);

    // Find language 'script' element and replace according to lang
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    if (lang != langfile) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].id && elements[i].id == 'lang') {
                var src = 'JavaScript/Localisation/strings_' + lang + '.js';
                document.head.replaceChild(newElement(src), elements[i]);
                // 'require' vil fire loadStrings() as soon as 'src' file loads
                require([src], function () {
                    loadStrings();
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```